# How to break ReadDirectoryChangesW function in MFC?

Tags: winapi, mfc, readdirectorychangesw

In MFC, I added a button in main dialog and `ReadDirectoryChangesW` function in this button. If the button is clicked, the specified folder will be monitored. The problem is if I clicked button, dialog cannot be worked, because program is still running in `ReadDirectoryChangesW` function. I want to be able to monitor documents while using the dialog freely, is there any solution?(please refer to code)

```
void CGGTransferDlg::OnBnClickedAutoStartButton(CString dir)
{
    HANDLE dwRootDirChangeHandle = CreateFileA(
        dir, /* pointer to the file name */
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,                /* (this is important to be FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY!) access (read-write) mode */
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,  /* (file share write is needed, or else user is not able to rename file while you hold it) share mode */
        NULL, /* security descriptor */
        OPEN_EXISTING, /* how to create */
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, /* file attributes */
        NULL /* file with attributes to copy */
        );
    if (dwRootDirChangeHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("error: %d", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    char notify[1024];
    memset(notify, 0, 1024);
    DWORD cbBytes;
    FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *pNotify = (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *)notify;
    char str1[MAX_PATH];

    CString NewResultFileLocal, NewResultFileSever, FileExtension;
    while (1)
    {

        if (ReadDirectoryChangesW(dwRootDirChangeHandle, &notify, sizeof(notify),
            TRUE, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME /*| FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE
                                               | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY*/, &cbBytes, NULL, NULL))//Fourth Parameter = TRUE, Get Subdirectory
        {
            int i = 0;
            memset(str1, 0, MAX_PATH);
            WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, pNotify->FileName, pNotify->FileNameLength / 2, str1, 99, NULL, NULL);

            NewResultFileLocal = str1;//char to cstring 
            NewResultFileLocal = dir + NewResultFileLocal;
            NewResultFileSever = str1;
            int n = NewResultFileSever.ReverseFind('\\');
            n = NewResultFileSever.GetLength() - n;
            NewResultFileSever = NewResultFileSever.Right(n - 1);

            FileExtension = PathFindExtension(NewResultFileSever);
            if (FileExtension == "aso")
                break;

            switch (pNotify->Action)
            {
            case FILE_ACTION_ADDED:
                Upload(NewResultFileLocal, NewResultFileSever);

                break;

            case FILE_ACTION_MODIFIED:
                printf("The file was modified. This can be a change in the time stamp or attributes.\n");
                break;
            case FILE_ACTION_REMOVED:
                LogSave("The file was removed from the directory: " + NewResultFileLocal);
                break;
            case FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_NEW_NAME:
                printf("The file was renamed and this is the new name.\n");
                break;
            case FILE_ACTION_RENAMED_OLD_NAME:
                printf("The file was renamed and this is the old name.\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Unknown command.\n");
            }

        }
    }
    ::CloseHandle(dwRootDirChangeHandle);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your UI doesn't work because you are using `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` in a *synchronous* loop within your UI thread. As such, the UI is blocked from processing other actions. Don't do that.

Move your loop to a separate worker thread, and have it notify your main UI as needed whenever a change is detected.

Also, use `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` *asynchronously* so that you can break the loop if you need to terminate the thread, such as during program exit. Create 2 event objects using `CreateEvent()`. Put one in an `OVERLAPPED` struct that you give to `ReadDirectoryChangesW()` so it can be signaled whenever a change occurs. Signal the other event manually when you want to terminate the thread. Then you can wait on both events using `WaitForMultipleObjects()`, and it will tell you whenever either event is signaled so you can act accordingly.

Comment: If you don't already know how to work with threads and inter-thread communications then I suggest you learn those separately before tackling this task.